# add a multiple angular material table in a single template

Tags: angular, angular-material

[image: See the following image]

> In the following image I had marked tabs in each tabs I want angular material data table please help me how to achieve it using angular 4
>   If I change datasource name for 2nd column it is not accepting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- HTML code -------------

<mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        <h2 class="example-h2">Tabs with text labels</h2>
        <mat-tab-group class="demo-tab-group">
            <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
                <div class="demo-tab-content">
                    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="countryname">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Coloumn Header Name </mat-header-cell>
                            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let abc">
                                {{abc.your value from displayedColumns1}}
                            </mat-cell>
                        </ng-container>
                        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
                    </mat-table>
                </div>
            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="Tab 2">
                <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource2>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="countryname">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Coloumn Header Name </mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let abc">
                            {{abc.your value from displayedColumns2}}
                        </mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>
                    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
                </mat-table>
            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="Tab 3" disabled>
                <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource3>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="countryname">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Coloumn Header Name </mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let abc">
                            {{abc.your value from displayedColumns3}}
                        </mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>
                    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
                </mat-table>
            </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>

-----------ts code -----------------
 displayedColumns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  dataSource;
   displayedColumns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  dataSource1;
   displayedColumns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  dataSource1;
```